# How to get Readable file descriptor from a byte-stream source from compressed files (gz)

Tags: c, io, gzip

I am newbie in C programming. I using a library which requires file descriptor from a byte-stream source. It is working perfectly fine when I have regular files. However, I have input inform of gz files. The total amount of compressed data I need to parse is about 5TB. I dont have enough space to uncompress all of them.

I have used following two methods but they doesnt seem to work,

```
input = gzopen (argv[i], "r");
```

Second method.

```
  arg = argv[1];
  cmd = malloc(sizeof(prefix) + strlen(arg) + 1);
  if (!cmd) {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: malloc: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
   sprintf(cmd, "%s%s", prefix, arg);
   input =  popen(cmd, "r");
```

I would be grateful if anyhelp can be provided.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "... they doesnt seem to work" needs more clarification. They do not lead to errors, yet do not run? I also fail to see what the `popen` example was supposed to do: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I get Segmentation fault as a run time exception.  It works with following method on uncompressed file.  

fd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);

I pass fd to the library and parsing works fine.

Comment: @user984201 Could you please post a complete program exhibiting the problem you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am inferring a little bit here since you don't show us the prototype of the library function you're using, but you say in a comment that this works for you when the file is uncompressed:

```
fd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
```

but using gzopen() or popen() does not.  So I gather that the library function you're using takes a file descriptor argument and reads and interprets the data itself.

This leads to what your immediate problem must be-- open() returns an "int" file descriptor, but gzopen() and popen() do not.

The zlib documentation defines gzopen() this way:

```
ZEXTERN gzFile ZEXPORT gzopen OF((const char *path, const char *mode));
```

So it returns a custom 'gzFile' file descriptor type; you can't pass this to a function that plans to do read(), expecting an int file descriptor.

Likewise, popen() returns a stdio FILE* file descriptor, not the int kind, and passing this to something that expects an int will also not work.

So if you wanted to use zlib, you would have to use its own gzread() function and then pass the data you read to your library function through an int type descriptor, possibly through a pipe. This would be cumbersome.

Your better bet might be using popen() as you tried, but use the stdio fileno() function to get the int descriptor that underlies the FILE*, and pass that to your library function.

So assuming that 'prefix' in your original code was something like "gzip -dc ", a command that would stream decompressed data from your file to stdout, we could modify your code to something like this (also, you assigned arg the value 'argv[1]' but used 'argv[i]' elsewhere-- I am assuming the '1' was a typo):

```
  char *prefix, *arg, *cmd;
  FILE *pinput;
  int fd;

  prefix = "gzip -dc ";
  arg = argv[i];
  cmd = malloc(strlen(prefix) + strlen(arg) + 1);
  if (!cmd) {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: malloc: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
   sprintf(cmd, "%s%s", prefix, arg);
   pinput =  popen(cmd, "r");
   fd = fileno(pinput);
```

Then you should be able to pass 'fd' to your library function and have it work as it did with the uncompressed data.

And don't forget to free(cmd) when you're all done with it!

Comment: This works, perfectly. I don't have words to thank you for not only posting answer but also explaining it in detail. I am really grateful to you.